# ClickHouse ALTER TABLE DELETE Exception Code 241

Tags: clickhouse

I'm having a problem on ALTER TABLE DELETE. I tried to execute ALTER DELETE with various **max_block_size** (8192, 4096, 2048, 1024). Also tried to change **merge_max_block_size** of the table (8192, 4096, 2048, 1024). No luck.
Full exception text:

> SQL Error [341]: ClickHouse exception, code: 341, host: 127.0.0.1, port: 40849; Code: 341, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Exception happened during execution of mutation 'mutation_94378.txt' with part '1_7146_15644_5_94355' reason: 'Code: 241, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 14.05 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4425496 bytes), maximum: 14.05 GiB: (avg_value_size_hint = 35.49267578125, avg_chars_size = 32.9912109375, limit = 8192): (while reading column market_code): (while reading from part /mnt/store/clickhouse/store/04d/04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67/1_7146_15644_5_94355/ from mark 0 with max_rows_to_read = 8192): While executing MergeTree (version 21.1.3.32 (official build))'. This error maybe retryable or not. In case of unretryable error, mutation can be killed with KILL MUTATION query (version 21.1.3.32 (official build))

clickhouse-server.log:

> 2021.03.23 08:30:04.621721 [ 268131 ] {}  AggregatingTransform: Aggregating
> 2021.03.23 08:30:04.621756 [ 268131 ] {}  Aggregator: Aggregation method: without_key
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.077471 [ 268131 ] {}  AggregatingTransform: Aggregated. 20 to 1 rows (from 0.00 B) in 0.683282494 sec. (29.27047037736635 rows/sec., 0.00 B/sec.)
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.077501 [ 268131 ] {}  Aggregator: Merging aggregated data
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.077675 [ 268131 ] {}  test.dt_customer (04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67) (MergerMutator): Mutating part 1_7146_15644_5_94355 to mutation version 94378
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078565 [ 268131 ] {}  test.dt_customer (04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67) (SelectExecutor): Key condition: unknown
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078581 [ 268131 ] {}  test.dt_customer (04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67) (SelectExecutor): MinMax index condition: unknown
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078589 [ 268131 ] {}  test.dt_customer (04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67) (SelectExecutor): Not using primary index on part 1_7146_15644_5_94355
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078597 [ 268131 ] {}  test.dt_customer (04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67) (SelectExecutor): Selected 1 parts by partition key, 1 parts by primary key, 15147 marks by primary key, 15147 marks to read from 1 ranges
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078658 [ 268131 ] {}  MergeTreeSelectProcessor: Reading 1 ranges from part 1_7146_15644_5_94355, approx. 124080000 rows starting from 0
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.078722 [ 268131 ] {}  InterpreterSelectQuery: FetchColumns -> Complete
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.162644 [ 268131 ] {}  MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage: 147.51 MiB.
> 2021.03.23 08:30:05.162743 [ 268131 ] {}  auto DB::IBackgroundJobExecutor::jobExecutingTask()::(anonymous class)::operator()() const: Code: 241, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 14.05 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 4426357 bytes), maximum: 14.05 GiB: (avg_value_size_hint = 35.49267578125, avg_chars_size = 32.9912109375, limit = 8192): (while reading column market_code): (while reading from part /mnt/store/clickhouse/store/04d/04d43c3a-9822-4168-a12a-664806ec3b67/1_7146_15644_5_94355/ from mark 0 with max_rows_to_read = 8192): While executing MergeTree, Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):
>
> 0. DB::Exception::Exception<char const*, char const*, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > >(int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, char const*&&, char const*&&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >&&, long&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >&&) @ 0x8625620 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 1. MemoryTracker::alloc(long) @ 0x8624f7d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 2. MemoryTracker::alloc(long) @ 0x8624ce4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 3. MemoryTracker::alloc(long) @ 0x8624ce4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 4. DB::DataTypeString::deserializeBinaryBulk(DB::IColumn&, DB::ReadBuffer&, unsigned long, double) const @ 0xea36a74 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 5. DB::MergeTreeReaderWide::readData(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator > const&, DB::IDataType const&, DB::IColumn&, unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, bool) @ 0xf6f8d19 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 6. DB::MergeTreeReaderWide::readRows(unsigned long, bool, unsigned long, std::__1::vector<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::allocator<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > >&) @ 0xf6f8030 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 7. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::DelayedStream::finalize(std::__1::vector<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn>, std::__1::allocator<COW<DB::IColumn>::immutable_ptr<DB::IColumn> > >&) @ 0xf700b9a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 8. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::startReadingChain(unsigned long, std::__1::deque<DB::MarkRange, std::__1::allocator<DB::MarkRange> >&) @ 0xf705066 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 9. DB::MergeTreeRangeReader::read(unsigned long, std::__1::deque<DB::MarkRange, std::__1::allocator<DB::MarkRange> >&) @ 0xf703c24 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 10. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::readFromPartImpl() @ 0xf6fe2b3 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 11. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::readFromPart() @ 0xf6fef0d in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 12. DB::MergeTreeBaseSelectProcessor::generate() @ 0xf6fd7ab in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 13. DB::ISource::tryGenerate() @ 0xf8d8df5 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 14. DB::ISource::work() @ 0xf8d8b1a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 15. DB::SourceWithProgress::work() @ 0xfa4045a in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 16. ? @ 0xf9129bc in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 17. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStepImpl(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::__1::atomic*) @ 0xf90f766 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 18. DB::PipelineExecutor::executeStep(std::__1::atomic*) @ 0xf90e0ec in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 19. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Chunk&) @ 0xf91c008 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 20. DB::PullingPipelineExecutor::pull(DB::Block&) @ 0xf91c250 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 21. DB::PipelineExecutingBlockInputStream::readImpl() @ 0xf909fd4 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 22. DB::IBlockInputStream::read() @ 0xe977455 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 23. DB::CheckSortedBlockInputStream::readImpl() @ 0xf063fc1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 24. DB::IBlockInputStream::read() @ 0xe977455 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 25. DB::ExpressionBlockInputStream::readImpl() @ 0xf64d537 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 26. DB::IBlockInputStream::read() @ 0xe977455 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 27. DB::MaterializingBlockInputStream::readImpl() @ 0xee33eed in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 28. DB::IBlockInputStream::read() @ 0xe977455 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 29. DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mutateAllPartColumns(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IMergeTreeDataPart>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IMergeTreeIndex const>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IMergeTreeIndex const> > > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IBlockInputStream>, long, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::ICompressionCodec> const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, bool, bool) const @ 0xf62ff49 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 30. DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mutatePartToTemporaryPart(DB::FutureMergedMutatedPart const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::MutationCommands const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, long, DB::Context const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<DB::IReservation, std::__1::default_delete<DB::IReservation> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0xf62c06e in /usr/bin/clickhouse
> 31. DB::StorageMergeTree::mutateSelectedPart(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::StorageMergeTree::MergeMutateSelectedEntry&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0xf3c6fc7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse
>     (version 21.1.3.32 (official build))

Comment: file an issue here https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues

Comment: thnx, posted an issue